# android can't import google play services

Tags: android, google-maps

From `SDK Manager` I have download the google play services, but when I try to add this lib to my project from `right click` then `import` the `existing android code into workshop` then when I select the google play services lib from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib` I got this error (see the pic below please) .

#### note

I have android support v4 (maybe this makes problems? I just tell you because I don't know if this would make mistakes).
[image]

Comment: just use C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services path..

Comment: @DhavalSodhaParmar when i did like u said, i got 4 projects to import and they are `libproject\google play serivce _lib` and `sample\map` and `sample\panorama` and `sample\plus`, should i select them or what?

Comment: yes select all... you have to just add mapapi key in mepsdemo.. then all are working fine...

Comment: @DhavalSodhaParmar if you mean the api key that i got from my sha1 and my package name, so i have it, or you mean another thing ?

Comment: when i added the 4 projects as u said, 4 new projects has been created and they all have errors in importing `com.google.android.gms`

Comment: no.. just forgat that & import that all project. you ll get google_play_services library..

Comment: @DhavalSodhaParmar so can i delete that projects which have errors? i tried to add reference to that `google play service lib` from project , property , android add but there is nothing to add

Comment: i mean i can't do the 4th step in this tutorial https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw

Comment: you have google play service lib project in your workspace..?

Comment: then just do your project-->properties-->android-->add-->"select google play service lib"-->ok-->ok.

Comment: no i don't have google play service lib in my project, i got this error ` Cannot import google-play-services_lib because the project name is in use` and when i went to project->android->add there is empty , nothing i can select from

Comment: @DhavalSodhaParmar i hope you got me, i know my english is bad

Comment: why you have delete all projects.. when you inport all 4 then one of them is google-play-services_lib that is your library project..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27327/discussion-between-dhaval-sodha-parmar-and-user2208349)

Comment: i in wrong delete them and now i don't have google play servcie in my sdk folder, i have to reinstall it again, :( :(

Comment: @DhavalSodhaParmar please don't go, i will be back when i finish install, and if i didn't get back you know that i died

Comment: @DhavalSodhaParmar i went to chat but i can't write there ,

Comment: @DhavalSodhaParmar go to chat please

Comment: @DhavalSodhaParmar write any answer, i will accpet it, and pleas follow me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745341/this-app-wont-run-without-google-play-services-which-are-missing-from-your-pho

Comment: In my experience, make sure the lib project and your project are in the same workspace directory (Ex. D:\workspace\ ). I know It's strange.  Only relative path reference to the lib project is OK.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Seems to be you have already imported the google-play-services_lib project and just deleted from eclipse ide but not in your hard drive workspace folder. Try deleting the google-play-services_lib project from your workspace folder and try importing the project again.

And make sure "Is Library" is checked in properties->Android of google-play-services_lib project.

Answer (score 1):

The Maps APIs for Android have been updated in the latest release of the Google Play Services library and have been rolled out to Android devices with the Play Store.

Please check this [link](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw).

if you have any query comment below.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that library already installed check my step by step tutorial to see if how you missed some step in using google map android v2 on emulator(android 4.2.2) have a look at to my blog: http://umut.tekguc.info/en/content/google-android-map-v2-step-step